# Loading JS after async JS in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I load google maps api using the async tag provided (below). I want to load a javascript file (that contains some class definitions that extend google maps api). How can I make sure the javascript is loaded after the Google Maps API JS is loaded?

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***************&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I tried putting this in the initMap function to load the javascript but it still loaded the js too quickly and consequently the "google is not defined" errors still occurred

```
 $.getScript("/assets/js/ContextMenu.js");
```

Comment: Just change your `&callback=initMap`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. my initMap() initalises the map on the page.

Comment: I'd think you could either change the `initMap` function to initiate your other plugin as well, or set the callback to something else that initiates your plugin and then calls `initMap`

Comment: That's what I'm asking, how do I load the other Javascript file after google maps has loaded. I can't find any way to control the order of loading

Comment: @CertainPerformance Please remove the duplicate, it doesn't do the same thing, I want to load in a file, not execute an arbitrary Javascript command.

Comment: You just need to set the `src` attribute of the script tag you append. If you're using jQuery already, I'd think `getScript` would work too

Comment: I'll just remake the question to be more specific. Feel free to delete this one.